# Angular(5) cli - Cloudinary - <cl-image> error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, cloudinary

So,

I am trying to implement cloudinary on our website
Following instructions I have this:

*app.module*

```
...
import { CloudinaryModule } from '@cloudinary/angular-4.x';
import { Cloudinary } from 'cloudinary-core/cloudinary-core-shrinkwrap';
...


const cloudinaryLib = {
  Cloudinary: Cloudinary
}
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CloudinaryModule.forRoot(cloudinaryLib, {cloud_name: 'mycloudname'})
    ...
  ]
  ...
});
```

and then in my view I have

```
<cl-image public-id="id-to-the-asset"></cl-image>
```

while doing *ng serve* I am getting an error

```
ERROR in Error at C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1/src/app/pages/a/a-page.component.html(10,3):  ("
  ></div>

  [ERROR ->]<cl-image public-id="site-assets/aaa"></cl-image>

  <div class="container">
")
```

Any ideas why?
The error says nothing to why

I am using

```
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0-rc.8",
...
"cloudinary-core": "^2.3.0",
"@cloudinary/angular-4.x": "^1.0.0",
...
"@angular/cli": "^1.5.0-rc.6",
```

Also, noticed that if I remove cl-image from the view and let the cli build the page I get these warnings:

> WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/@cloudinary/angular-4.x/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
>   5659:15-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
>   expression
>       at ImportLazyContextDependency.getWarnings (C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\ContextDependency.js:39:18)
>       at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:703:24)
>       at Compilation.finish (C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:561:9)
>       at applyPluginsParallel.err (C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:506:17)
>       at C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:289:11
>       at _addModuleChain (C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:507:11)
>       at processModuleDependencies.err (C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:477:14)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)  @ ./node_modules/@cloudinary/angular-4.x/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
>   @
>   ./node_modules/@cloudinary/angular-4.x/src/cloudinary-image-source.directive.js
>   @ ./node_modules/@cloudinary/angular-4.x/src/cloudinary.module.js  @
>   ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js  @ ./src/main.ts  @ multi
>   webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
>
> WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/@cloudinary/angular-4.x/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
>   5675:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
>   expression
>       at ImportLazyContextDependency.getWarnings (C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\ContextDependency.js:39:18)
>       at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:703:24)
>       at Compilation.finish (C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:561:9)
>       at applyPluginsParallel.err (C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:506:17)
>       at C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:289:11
>       at _addModuleChain (C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:507:11)
>       at processModuleDependencies.err (C:/DEVELOPMENT/app1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:477:14)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)  @ ./node_modules/@cloudinary/angular-4.x/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
>   @
>   ./node_modules/@cloudinary/angular-4.x/src/cloudinary-image-source.directive.js
>   @ ./node_modules/@cloudinary/angular-4.x/src/cloudinary.module.js  @
>   ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js  @ ./src/main.ts  @ multi
>   webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts

**EDITED**

I downgraded to latest 4.x angular version and don't get build errors nor warnings... but I do get

```
'cl-image' is not a known element:
```

so, still not working

Comment: Seems adventurous to be running Angular 5 with a library that has Angular 4.x in it's name.

Comment: yeah, I thought the same.... will be downgrading back to the stable 4x version and let's see

Comment: Did you see their [CodePen](https://codepen.io/team/Cloudinary/project/editor/AxrvPZ), may have some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. I'd suggest you need

```
import * as cloudinary from 'cloudinary-core/cloudinary-core-shrinkwrap';
```

and

```
CloudinaryModule.forRoot(cloudinary,
  {
    cloud_name: 'ccloudd'
  } as CloudinaryConfiguration),
```

Comment: well, I downgraded and it works... just needed to go through the different settings again.... so cheers!